# vtiger 6 can't add user

Tags: php, mysql, vtiger

When I try and create a user, it goes to a blank white page.  When I go back to crm, no user was created.  Is there a fix?

so for example there was another issue where webforms did not want to save.  so i applied a fix i found somewhere which was to add a database table.  the code for that is below.  so i was looking for similar help with this new issue above.  don't know if it's going to be a mysql modification or a php modification, but hopefully someone knows something.

```
CREATE TABLE `vtiger_webforms_field` (
`id` int(19) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`webformid` int(19) NOT NULL,
`fieldname` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`neutralizedfield` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`defaultvalue` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
`required` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `webforms_webforms_field_idx` (`id`),
KEY `fk_1_vtiger_webforms_field` (`webformid`),
KEY `fk_2_vtiger_webforms_field` (`fieldname`),
CONSTRAINT `fk_1_vtiger_webforms_field` FOREIGN KEY (`webformid`) REFERENCES `vtiger_webforms` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT `fk_3_vtiger_webforms_field` FOREIGN KEY (`fieldname`) REFERENCES `vtiger_field` (`fieldname`) ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

Comment: no error, even with display_errors on and the error_log file also shows no errors.  it goes to index.php with all blank white page from the user entry page (index.php?module=Users&parent=Settings&view=Edit)

Comment: white page means fatal error. maybe it's not hitting where you have display_errors turned on or if it's at ini level it's being disabled further down.